# Add line to file while reading line by line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to appned line(s) to file while reading a file using bash loop ? Below the code that I am reading the file and pseudocode what I want to achieve. I wanted to be done at the same file and not creating a new one and then copy the contents to the original one

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/path/to/txt/file"
while read -r line
do
  if [ line == 'test' ]; then
  # Append some text to next line 
done < "$input"
```

Comment: The comment (_"# Append some text to next line"_) in the code and the wording (_"add line to file"_ and _"appned [sic] line(s) to file"_) in the post are not consistent. Appending some text to a line and appending a line to a file are not the same thing. The question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is by `sed`:

```bash
sed -r 's/(line)/\1\nNew added line\n/g' /path/to/txt/file
```

Comment: No need for `cat`: `sed -r 's/(line)/\1\nNew added line\n/g' /path/to/txt/file` Since it is a full line that is the target, better to use anchors as well: `sed -r 's/^(line)$/\1\nNew added line\n/g'`

Comment: Sure, are two equivalent forms.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca  They produce the same output, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: They are not equivalent. And potentially [useless use](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#cat)

Comment: I edited the post to make you happy!

Answer (score 1):

A simple any version `sed`:

```bash
sed '/test/ a\
Text appended
' /path/to/txt/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Write all of your text out to a second file, then copy that tempfile over your original file.

Also, I know you said it was psuedo-code, but I went ahead and fixed some of the other typos/syntax errors you had in your script. The following does exactly what you need.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
input="input.txt"
outfile="/tmp/outfile.txt"
extra_text="foobarwaz"

echo '' > ${outfile}

while read -r line ; 
do
  echo "${line}" >> ${outfile}
  if [ "${line}" == 'test' ]; then
    echo ${extra_text} >> ${outfile}
  fi
      
done < "$input"

cp ${outfile} ${input}
```